# Marketing Cloud preference - Customization

Tags: marketing-cloud, customization, preference-center

I wanted to know if there is a way to customize the Marketing Cloud preference center without AMP script. 
I didn't find a helpful answer.

Thank you!

Comment: What kind of customizations are you looking to make?  Brand Builder, Profile Attributes and Publication Lists do allow for some customizations.

Answer (score 6):

Unfortunately - the general answer is no, there is no way to make a customized preference center without Ampscript (or SSJS). That said, it's possible you could use a Smart Form to submit into a data extension and use the data extension as your subscriber preferences, but there are limitations to this, primarily being that opt outs / unsubscribes would not sync upstream to Salesforce (if you're using the connector).

Answer (score 5):

Unfortunately no, the OOTB preference center of Marketing Cloud is not customizable. Just the colors and the logo when Brand Builder is enabled. Regarding the [translations](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_es_understand_international_sends.htm&type=5), it is done automatically based on the language of the web browser.